# Sorting in a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I am creating a generic class that has a method that is supposed to sort through an array collection that may either be a Book or it may be a CD. I implemented Comparable in the two type classes and am trying to sort the array in the GenericCollection class.

My method looks like this right now:

```
public void sort(){
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < collection.length; j++) {
            if (((T)collection[i]).compareTo((T)collection[j]) > 0){
                T t = (T)collection[i];
                collection[i] = collection[j];
                collection[j] = t;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error that Object is not comparable. If I try to cast to type T then I get the error that T is undefined for CompareTo. If I try something like:

```
<T extends Comparable>
```

I can compile but I get a runtime error even though I have Comparable defined in both types that are using this class.

How do I get the Generic type to be able to run the compareTo methods in their own classes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the type of collection?

Comment: And what is the runtime error?

Comment: @Justin. Its a generic collection of type T... in other words it can either be a book or a CD (client classes). I get the error while using either type.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, is there a reason you are not using `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`

Comment: @Daniel. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method compareTo(Object) is undefined for the type Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to implement your own sort algorithm, try to declare the type parameter of your generic collection class as

```
 <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

This means, your class would be declared like this:

```
 class GenericCollection<T extends Comparable<T>> {  ... }
```

And of course, your book or CD classes should implement this exact type:

```
 class Book implements Comparable<Book> { ... }

 class CD implements Comparable<CD> { ... }
```

If you use the parameter `<T extends Comparable>`, you are using a **raw type**, and these are only for compatibility with old (pre-generics) code, should never be used in new code.

Comment: Is this for the top of the method, or is it for use when I call the constructor?

Answer (score 7):

You should be using a built-in sort, however to answer your question you need to have.

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

or the more obscure

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

See

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

The moral of the story: If you are not going to use a built-in function which does exactly what you want, you should at least understand it first because it might have some tips for you. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this addressed the problem but what worked for me was to place this in the class specification instead of the method.